# Why are there 2 parentheses in EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector")))?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was simply wondering when using Selenium for python why there are 2 parentheses in between the `element_to_be_clickable` and the `By` methods, such as:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector")))
```

This is also visble in the docs - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Any answers?

Cheers

Comment: Obviously, this is because `element_to_be_clickable()` should get iterable object as argument. If parenteses confusing you, you might use `EC.element_to_be_clickable([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector"])` :)

Comment: @Andersson what is "obvious" to one is not always obvious to another. That's one of the reasons this site exists.

Comment: @JeffC, `tuple` is the very basics of `python` and I'm quite sure that there is more than enough information in web about what is it, how to use it and what for..

Comment: @Andersson I don't disagree with you but when you are starting and you don't know what to call it, it's hard to search for.

Comment: @Andersson The issue isn't about knowing `tuples` (which I know thanks) but `locators` in Selenium. And given that your comment slightly differs from the answer below, I still consider, even on second thought, that the question was legitimate :) Relax my friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) the method [`element_to_be_clickable`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) expects one argument: a locator. A locator is a tuple of (by, path).

So the inner pair of parentheses are for the tuple literal, while the outer parentheses are for bounding the function parameters (only one in this case).

Comment: Can I use a list instead of a tuple? Andersson's comment above suggests doing so but doesn't mention explicitly that a tuple `(by, path)` can be replaced with a list `[by, path]` as the `locator` argument for this method.

Comment: This depends on the implementation in the API. The documentation says that the argument can be a locator (which "is a tuple of (by, path)"), a locator text, or a Web Element. It is likely it will also work with a list, but if the documentation speaks of tuple, better use tuple. If readability is the issue, you can also write `EC.element_to_be_clickable(tuple([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector"]))`